# Check if payment information has been added

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to check whether or not payment information has been added to the users' account before initiating an IAP?

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: All you can do is check `canMakePayments()`. If it returns `false`, hide your store interface. If it returns `true` then display it. If payment information is required then this will need to be dealt with by the user when they attempt to purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine that apple would allow you to know this **specifically**. But I do know that you can get certain error codes for different things if there's a failure if you query for a payment. Best thing you can probably do is try to charge for a payment anyways and handle the error codes accordingly.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerror